# Pi RGB controler with Python over the web using PHP and SSH. It is good idea?

Tags: python, php, ssh, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

Iam made Python script that can control my BLE RGB strip, also I made web page with php that connect to Pi via ssh and run Python script. My question is, **is there a better way ?**

I will mark my favorite answer in few days. I hope someone will see this and get same inspiration like me.

Thanks for all comments.

My PHP code.

```
?php

$mode = htmlspecialchars($_GET["mode"]);
$color = htmlspecialchars($_GET["color"]);

function color_name_to_hex($color_name)
{
    // standard 147 HTML color names
    $colors  =  array(
        'aliceblue'=>'F0F8FF',
        'antiquewhite'=>'FAEBD7'
         ...;

    $color_name = strtolower($color_name);
    if (isset($colors[$color_name]))
    {
        return ('#' . $colors[$color_name]);
    }
    else
    {
        return ($color_name);
    }
}
$connection = ssh2_connect('*ip*', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, '*login*', '*passsword*');

switch ($mode) {
  case 'on':
      $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'python on.py');
    break;
  case 'off':
      $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'python off.py');
    break;
  case 'color':

        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'python color.py \''.color_name_to_hex($color).'\'');

    break;
  default:
      ssh2_disconnect ($connection);
    break;
}


ssh2_disconnect ($connection);
```

Comment: all depend what you need. I would rather use Python/Flask to create web page and I would run it directly on Rasperry Pi. This way I don't need `PHP` and don't have to use `ssh` and don't need `login/password` to Rasperry Pi. And web server could has two urls - one to turn on and second to turn of. Eventually it could get option in url (without using `form`) so I could use it in other program - GUI on desktop, or app on mobile. Web page would works as `RestAPI`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Python`/`Flask` to run this web page. And I would run it directly on Pi so I wouldn't need to use `login`/`password`

This is (more or less) `PHP` converted to `Flask` to run directly on PI (without SSH)

I used port `8080` because standard port `80` would need root privileges.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

def color_name_to_hex(color_name):
    # standard 147 HTML color names
    colors = {
        'aliceblue': '#F0F8FF',
        'antiquewhite': '#FAEBD7',
        # ...
    }
    
    color_name = color_name.lower()
    
    # get `colors[color_name]` (first `color_name` in get()) or use `color_name` (second `color_name` in get())
    color_hex = colors.get(color_name, color_name)
    
    return color_hex

@app.route('/')
def index():
    mode = request.args.get('mode')
    color = request.args.get('color')

    if mode == 'on':
        subprocess.run('python on.py')
    elif mode == 'off':
        subprocess.run('python off.py')
    elif mode == 'color':
        color_hex = color_name_to_hex(color)
        subprocess.run(f"python color.py '{color_hex}'")

    return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

---

Eventually I would create separated URLs for every command

```
http://ip_of_raspberry:8080/turn/on
http://ip_of_raspberry:8080/turn/off
http://ip_of_raspberry:8080/color/red
```

And later I would use Python to build desktop GUI (`tkinter`, `PyQt`, `PyGTK`, `wxPython`) or mobile App ([Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home)).

---

```
from flask import Flask, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

def color_name_to_hex(color_name):
    # standard 147 HTML color names
    colors = {
        'aliceblue': '#F0F8FF',
        'antiquewhite': '#FAEBD7',
        # ...
    }
    
    color_name = color_name.lower()
    
    # get `colors[color_name]` (first `color_name` in get()) or use `color_name` (second `color_name` in get())
    color_hex = colors.get(color_name, color_name)
    
    return color_hex

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'HELLO WORLD'
    
@app.route('/turn/on')
def turn_on():
    subprocess.run('python on.py')
    return 'OK turn on'
    
@app.route('/turn/off')
def turn_off():
    subprocess.run('python off.py')
    return 'OK turn off'

@app.route('/color/<color_name>')
def color(color_name):
    color_hex = color_name_to_hex(color_name)
    subprocess.run(f"python color.py '{color_hex}'")
    return f'OK color {color_name}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

---

I use `subprocess` to run your `on.py`, `off.py`, `color.py` but I would rather use `import on`, `import off`, `import color` and execute function from imported modules but it would need to put code in function in `on.py`, `off.py`, `color.py` (which probably you didn't)

---

BTW: this way you would build something similar to [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) which also use Python [code](https://github.com/home-assistant/core)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I never hear about Kivy and sounds good.But I probably in future will switch from pi to something cheaper like PyBoard or Arduino. I enjoyed reading your approach and learning something.

Comment: with web server you can change color even using web browser or python module `reuqests` or `urllib`. I don't know if `Arduino` can run web server but maybe it can run something smaller - like `message queue` - ie. [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) - and then you can use python module [paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) or console programs `sub` `pub` from [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/download/). I use `MQTT` to send temperature from RPi to main computer and other users may use `MQTT` to get temperature from main computer.

Comment: [MQTT Tutorial for Raspberry Pi, Arduino, and ESP8266](https://www.baldengineer.com/mqtt-tutorial.html)